# jquery - clear value from input when another value is empty

Tags: jquery, html, html-input

i have 2 inputfields

```
<input id="pass1" name="pass1" value="" size="12" type="password" />
<input id="pass2" name="pass2" value="" size="12" type="password" />
```

when `id="pass1"` has no value (is empty) and `id="pass2"` has a value i want to clear `id="pass2"` with jquery before i submit the form.

is that possible?

Comment: When you want it be get cleared? on which event key events or load event?

Comment: i want to clear it before i submit the form if this is possible

Comment: @bernte  i updated my answer.. input's will be checked on submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think checking the second input is useless and has no logical reason, i mean in both cases you end up with empty `#pass2`

```
$("form").on('submit',function(){
      if($("#pass1").val() == ''){
          $("#pass2").val('');
          return false;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See you have to do a form submit and check if the `#pass1` is empty or not and `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form to submit.

```
$(function(){
  $("yourFormId").submit(function(e){
    if($("#pass1").val() == ''){
       $("#pass2").val('');
       e.preventDefault(); //<----stop the form submission here after clearing
    }
  });
});
```